# How to test (in depth) if the JDK is correctly installed?

Tags: java, testing

I suspect something is wrong with my system's version of Java. Certain apps are seg faulting or running out of memory or having linking errors. If I had installed the JDK from source, I would just do something like "make test" and see which tests fail. However, it looks like building the JDK from source is not easy. Is there a standard test to find issues with a Java installation? I am looking for something more in-depth than just building a HelloWorld app, which I have done.

I am using OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu 18.04, installed via apt install openjdk-8.

Comment: Java does not depend much on the operating system. If you can run `java -version`, then you should be fine. In your case, I would focus on applications you are using, and look at the dumps created by application crashes.

Comment: "Linking errors" sound very suspicious, you mean that you can't start `java`? Could you provide some samples of error messages here?

Comment: Just posted some more details.

Comment: Actually, the IntelliJ error is hard to replicate and depends on the VM max size. The linkage error includes Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/zach/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/182.4892.20/jre64/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libX11.so.6: failed to map segment from shared object
 at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) and com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:78)

Comment: Some searching around indicates that the "failed to map segment from shared object" could be related to incorrect filesystem permissions. In particular, if your `/tmp` or `TMPDIR` is set to disallow executables, you might not be able to temporarily decompress shared objects there, which might be the source of your troubles.

Comment: The permissions on /tmp are 777 and TMPDIR is not assigned :(

Comment: IntelliJ seg faults on startup. Maven is sensitive to -Xmx, working best at 1000m. Higher than 1500m and it can't allocate virtual memory to start the VM, around 1200m complains that it couldn't link to some Guava library, although this stopped since I changed the version of GNUTLS. Lower than 1000m is not enough memory for the VM. I tried ripping out Java, Maven, and Idea and reinstalling them, which did not fix things. I tried Java 8 and 11, different sources for the JRE binary, etc. I want to test the JRE/JDK directly if possible.

Comment: @DanielPryden actually, after more searching, the Idea issue went away when I ran it as the root user, so you were probably right about the permissions issue there. Interestingly, as root, I created a desktop icon, and starting through that as a non-root user works fine. So that's weird.

Comment: Some problem still persists though, since JShell seems to be having similar issues.

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple, just open command prompt and type

```
java
```

Then hit enter, if it shows you a lot of info about java like version and other info the you are ready to go.

***Make sure your environment pat has been set correctly.***

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Starting java prints the expected usage message. I am hoping there is a more in-depth test to check that Java is working correctly in a range of cases, much like "make test" would do for a from-source C compilation.